# "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Getting the following error while adding serverless middleware to my lambda `"getRecordsFromRequestId"`:

```json
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'gmceeservicing-dev-getRecordsFromRequestId'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "trace": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'gmceeservicing-dev-getRecordsFromRequestId'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}
```

Here is my serverless.yml:

```yaml
getRecordsFromRequestId:
    handler: lambda/getRecordsFromRequestId/index.main
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: /getRecordsFromRequestId
          method: get
          cors: true
    middleware:
      pre: 
        - preAuth.main
```

What has to be changed? If anybody could help? I want API to run.

Comment: I have two questions: 1. what is `gmceeservicing-dev-getRecordsFromRequestId`? Is this part of your lambda package, or some internal library? 2. Could you add a minimal (or approximate) folder structure of your project to your question?

Comment: sure.
1. getRecordsFromRequestId is my lambda in the repo gmceeservicing which is at development stage. This is not any internal library.
2. gmceeservicing
     |
     lambda
     |
     getRecordsFromRequestId
     |
      preAuth.js - serverless middleware
     index.js
    |
    serverless.yml.
   I have given a rough folder structure, if this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Are you using integration with Serverless Dashboard/Console? If yes, could you try turning it off and seeing if the issue persist? I remember seeing similar issues in the past that were connected to a bug in that integration